# change screen orientation of particular view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-manifest, landscape-portrait

My application is by default in Portrait mode. So i have declared

```
<activity
            android:name=".phone.activities.BasePhoneActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:logo="@drawable/home_icon"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/ItemListTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" />
```

in manifest file.

[image]

And as per screenshot my phone is in portrait mode. Now i rotate my phone to left side (90 degree) and in landscape mode I just want to change the orientation of that Layout with Arrow Image. But i have already given `android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"` in manifest file, I don't get `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` event in my activity and I can't change that layout.

Answer (score 0):

The view can't be forced -or I don't know how. The activity it can be.

Forcing the whole activity to landscape for example can be done in manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivtyName" 
       android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                >
```

Forcing a view:

- detect the situation, when need to be rotated.
- at `onDraw()` apply a transformation for 90 degree, you have to detect the sizes on transformed position